# How can I optimize GridDB's performance for time-series data?

Tags: performance, optimization, configuration, time-series, griddb

I'm storing a large amount of time-series data in GridDB, and I want to optimize the database's performance for this data type. However, I must figure out what settings or configurations I must adjust to achieve the best performance.

Here's what I have so far:

```
{
  "dataStore": [
    {
      "name": "my_container",
      "type": "TIME_SERIES",
      "columnInfo": [
        {
          "columnName": "timestamp",
          "type": "TIMESTAMP",
          "options": "TIMESTAMP"
        },
        {
          "columnName": "value",
          "type": "DOUBLE"
        }
      ],
      "rowKey": {
        "keyType": "TIMESTAMP"
      },
      "timeSeriesProperties": {
        "expirationDivisionCount": 16,
        "expirationMillisec": 1000,
        "rowExpiration": false,
        "compressionMethod": "LZ4"
      }
    }
  ],
  "partitionInfo": {
    "partitionType": "HASH",
    "partitionCount": 4
  }
}
```